# Executing wso2server.bat of WSO2 Identity Service is not working yet in windows 8.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have just downloaded the WSO2 Identity Server Version 5.0.0 in Windows 8.1. with jdk 1.7.0_79 set in the path.

Then I opened a windows cmd and ran `wso2server.bat --run`

The traces I get are:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\IDENTI~1\bin\..

INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.PatchInstaller} -  Patch changes detected
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification started
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.console} -  Patch verification successfully completed.
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 8.1 6.3, amd64
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_79
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02,
Oracle Corporation
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\IDENTI~1\bin\..
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\IDENTI~1\bin\..\tmp
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : Usr, es-ES, Europe/Paris
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The running OS : Windows 8.1 is not a tested O
perating System for running WSO2 Carbon
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is curre
ntly being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.iwa.ui.internal.Activator} -  Integrated Windows Authenticator enabled in the
system
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Initializing Directory Server with working directory C:\Users\Alva
ro\Desktop\IDENTI~1\bin\..\repository\data\org.wso2.carbon.directory and port 10389
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.social.internal.SocialComponent} -  Social Activity bundle is activated
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.remote.internal.CarbonRemoteUserStoreDSComponent} -  Carbon Remote User Store act
ivated successfully.
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 76ms
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.internal.ApplicationManagementServiceComponent} -  Identity ApplicationManag
ementComponent bundle is activated
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.

Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled
```

After that, the process keeps running at the `Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled` sentence and never ends.

Maybe this version of WSO2 Carbon is not working over Windows 8.x?

Comment: We have not tested WSO2 Identity Server on Windows 8.x platform. So it would be pretty hard to pinpoint issues like these without testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is Windows 8.1. I'm running WSO2 IS 5.0.0 on it.

This is my print screen: [Windows 8.1 Pro runnig WSO2 IS 5.0.0](http://www.arthroscopy.com.br/images/wso2is.jpg)

Have you tried to install the WSO2 IS Service Pack?

Maybe it helps.